# Having issue with subprocess library in python during text extraction from image using OCR

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, ocr

I have been using python OCR code to extract text from the image but i am getting some error. I think error is with subprocess library, however it is built in library. So i couldn't figure out the error exactly. can anyone please help me in resolving this error. My code and error are as below.

OCR code

```
       import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def ocr(path):
    temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    process.communicate()

    with open(temp.name + '.txt', 'r') as handle:
        contents = handle.read()

    os.remove(temp.name + '.txt')
    os.remove(temp.name)

    return contents

str = ocr("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\MS Thesis\\opencv-text-detection\\opencv-text-detection\\images\\sign.jpg")
print(str)
```

by executing th above code I got following error

[7]: runfile('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis/python text detection.py', wdir='C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis/python text detection.py', wdir='C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis')

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis/python text detection.py", line 26, in 
    str = ocr("C:\Users\hp\Desktop\MS Thesis\opencv-text-detection\opencv-text-detection\images\sign.jpg")

File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/MS Thesis/python text detection.py", line 15, in ocr
    process = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', path, temp.name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 171, in **init**
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I have been using Python 3.7.1 with anaconda on window 7

Answer (score 0):

Look like there is an error because it cannot found the file
if the file is in the same directory I will recommend you use:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'file_dir')
```